# How to set True(Checked) or False(Unchecked) values for a CHECK BOX and send the values to a webservice

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a check box.I have to set True or False values for that check box .If that check box is checked means it has to set to True and if it is unchecked means it has to set to False.I have to store that True or False values in a String and sent it to a web service.I have coded the web service coding.But i am unable to send the check box data ...

Can any one help me....

Thanks in Advance

```
Here is my Code



     CheckBox chalan_recvd = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chalan_recvd);

  chalan_recvd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(buttonView.isChecked()){


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "checked", 1).show();

         Util.key="true";


            }


            else 
            {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "unchecked", 1).show();

            Util.key="false";

            }



        }

      });
```

In the above program Util is the seperate java file where i have saved all the declarations for a easy use.in Util i have saved like this

public static String key=null;

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)

Comment: Please provide the code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here..

```
public static String strValue = null;

if (checkbox..isChecked()) 
    {
    strValue = "True";
    } else {
    strValue = "False";
    }
```

Send string value to webservice..

Answer (score 2):

Use This

```
show_pwd_check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.show_pwd_check);
show_pwd_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) {
System.out.println("check box clicked");
} else {

System.out.println("Somthing happen wrong");

}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an export file with value you have put the save that value on "strValue":

so like:

```
"chalan_recvd" + ":" + strValue +
```

Save a json file and when you have online send to IP of webservice.